# Inverse of matrix with blocks of ones

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis

It seems that there is a nice inverse for matrices that can be written as a diagonal matrix plus a symmetric matrix consisting of scaled blocks of ones.

Consider a real matrix of the form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}{1}_{r_{1}\times r_{1}}+b_{1}I_{r_{1}} & a_{12}{1}_{r_{1}\times r_{2}} & a_{13}{1}_{r_{1}\times r_{3}} \\
a_{12}{1}_{r_{2}\times r_{1}} & a_{22}{1}_{r_{2}\times r_{2}}+b_{2}I_{r_{2}} & a_{23}{1}_{r_{2}\times r_{2}} \\
a_{13}{1}_{r_{3}\times r_{1}} & a_{23}{1}_{r_{2}\times r_{2}} & a_{33}{1}_{r_{3}\times r_{3}} +b_{3}I_{r_{3}}
\end{pmatrix}$$
The $r_i$ are growing linearly in the matrix size $n$, the $a_{ij}$ are bounded in absolute value as $n$ grows, while the $b_i$ are bounded and bounded away from $0$. The matrices $1_{r_i \times r_j}$ are matrices of all ones of the appropriate dimensions, and $I_{r_i}$ are identity matrices.

Are there techniques to analyze the inverse of such a matrix? In the 2-by-2 case, we can compute that the inverse is 
\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{b_{1}^{-1}}{r_{1}}{1}_{r_{1}\times r_{1}}+b_{1}^{-1}I_{r_{1}}+O(1/n^{2}) & O(1/n^{2})\\
O(1/n^{2}) & -\frac{b_{2}^{-1}}{r_{2}}{1}_{r_{2}\times r_{2}}+b_{2}^{-1}I_{r_{2}}+O(1/n^{2})
\end{pmatrix} 
Is there an easy way to see why this should generalize?

Comment: If the r’s are equal then the matrix is $A\otimes I_r$, so finding the inverse is easy.

Comment: Have you tried row and column reduction to get rid of most of the nonzero items? When I do it I get 9 nonzero entries off the diagonal, which might be handled by adding three rank 1 matrices to a diagonal matrix.  Gerhard "Zero Is Easier Than One" Paseman. 2018.04.03.

Comment: Oops, I did it wrong. I get six nonzero entries for the non diagonal blocks, and the diagonal blocks look like arrowheads of b's and (-b)'s. My guess is that this form can be analyzed and generalized to more than three diagonal blocks.  I would expect a nice inverse for this reduced form.  Gerhard "Is Struck By The Direction" Paseman, 2018.04.03.

Comment: It seems that we can write the matrix in question as $XX^T$ for an $X$ that has the same form, so there may be a connection to projection that makes it obvious why the off-diagonal entries should be small.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Wouldn't it be $A\otimes 1_r + \operatorname{diag}(b_1,b_2,b_3)\otimes I_r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\newcommand{\PP}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}$

Is there an easy way to see why this should generalize? Yes.

Indeed, this can be extended to any number of blocks. Say a matrix $M$ consists of $q\times q$ blocks, with its $ij$-block given by the formula 
\begin{equation}
 a_{ij}1_{r_i\times r_j}+b_i\de_{ij}I_{r_i},
\end{equation}
where $i,j=1,\dots,q$ and $\de_{ij}$ is the Kronecker symbol. The $ij$-block of the inverse matrix $M^{-1}$ has the same form: 
\begin{equation}
 c_{ij}1_{r_i\times r_j}+d_i\de_{ij}I_{r_i}
\end{equation}
for some real $c_{ij}$ and $d_i$.

Noting that $1_{r\times s}1_{s\times t}=s1_{r\times t}$, we see that the $ij$-block of the identity matrix $MM^{-1}$ is 
\begin{equation}
 \sum_k (a_{ik}1_{r_i\times r_k}+b_i\de_{ik}I_{r_i})(c_{kj}1_{r_k\times r_j}+d_k\de_{kj}I_{r_k})
 =u_{ij}1_{r_i\times r_j}+b_id_i\de_{ij}I_{r_i}, 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 u_{ij}:=a_{ij}d_j+\sum_k(a_{ik}r_k+\de_{ik}b_k)c_{kj}. 
\end{equation}
That is, 
\begin{equation}
 D_d=D_{1/b},\quad AD_b+(AD_r+D_b)C=0,
\end{equation}
where $D_v$ stands for the diagonal matrix with the coordinates of the vector $v=(v_1,\dots,v_q)$ on the diagonal, $d:=(d_1,\dots,d_q)$, $b:=(b_1,\dots,b_q)$, $1/b:=(1/b_1,\dots,1/b_q)$, $r:=(r_1,\dots,r_q)$, $A:=(a_{ij})$, and
\begin{multline*}
C:=(c_{ij})=-(AD_r+D_b)^{-1}AD_b
=-(I_q+D_r^{-1}A^{-1}D_b)^{-1}(AD_r)^{-1}AD_{1/b} \\ 
=-(I_q+D_r^{-1}A^{-1}D_b)^{-1}D_{1/(br)}\sim-D_{1/(br)}  
\end{multline*}
if, for instance, $A^{-1}$ exists and $\min_i|r_i|\to\infty$, where $br:=(b_1r_1,\dots,b_qr_q)$. Thus, the $ij$-block $c_{ij}1_{r_i\times r_j}+d_i\de_{ij}I_{r_i}$ of the inverse matrix $M^{-1}$ behaves as 
\begin{equation}
 \Big(\frac1{b_i}\,I_{r_i}-\frac1{b_ir_i}\,1_{r_i\times r_i}\Big)\de_{ij}, 
\end{equation}
as desired.